How to estimate $n$ so that the product of the first $n$ primes is greater than a given number?
Given $p \in \mathbb{N}$ I want to approximate how many primes $n$ I need so that $$\prod_{i=1}^np_i>4\sqrt{p}$$ with $p_i$ being the $i$-th prime, e.g. $p_1=2,~p_2=3,p_3=5, \dots$
In Schoof it says "A weak form of the prime number theorem shows that this can be achieved with at most $O(log(p))$ primes $p_i$, each of size at most $O(log(p))$."
I know that the $i$-th prime can be approximated as $i\cdot log(i)$ (as stated in the prime number theorem), however I don't see how that would lead to this solution.

Your product, the $n$-th primorial is estimated by $e^{(1+o(1))n\log(n)}$, see here. This gives you the $n$ you need.

@DietrichBurde working with the estimation $e^{(1+o(1))n~log(n)}$, wouldn't I get that $n~log(n)$ needs to be of size $O(log(\sqrt{p}))$? Subsequently, is $O(log(p))$ just a very rough approximation?

Schoof uses only a "weak" form of the PNT. Using the "strong" PNT, it should become better. In the title you only ask how to estimate such $n$, and not how good the approximation should be. In the text below you are saying nothing about it as well.
